# Bootstraps noob: how do i put these cool bars in my page?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Just started using bootstrap to make my own website and post my accomplishments on it. The problem is, i don't know how to put these cool ''examples'' in my page. Any help please?

Comment: Please review [ask] questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, just do some copy & paste...

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template